# $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ be continuous , differentiable function such that $f'$ is bounded on $[a,b]$ ; then is $f' \in \mathcal R[a,b]$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, riemann-integration

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ be continuous , differentiable function ( having one sided derivatives at $a$ and $b$ ) such that $f'$ is bounded on $[a,b]$  ; then is $f'$ Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Not true.  The first example given appeared in

> Vito Volterra, Alcune osservazioni sulle funzioni punteggiate
>   discontinue, Gior- nale di Matematiche, (1881) vol. 19, 76–86.

[Added note:]

Maybe some of you are at a library with inadequate archives ... or don't like reading Italian.  So I will try a little harder to help.

All you need to do is take a fat Cantor set and construct your function around that. My friend James Foran included a construction of such a function on page 267 
in his book

> Foran, James: *Fundamentals of Real Analysis*. Marcel Dekker lnc., New
>   York 1991, 496 pp.,

I thought this was pretty well known. It was precisely the motivation that Lebesgue gave for developing a new theory of integration.  If you look in the early literature of integration theory you find a great deal of attention on "improper" integrals--how best to handle unbounded functions.  Volterra's example shows that the Riemann integral doesn't handle even the bounded functions correctly.

Comment: Thanks! I was about to describe a counterexample - that was going to be a pain...

Comment: @B.S. Thomson : Can you please give any link or open-access perhaps ..

Comment: @Saun Dev  Ok, I added a bit more to the answer.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson : Is there a pdf or djvu file of that book ? You are right , I really have not much access to varied books or journal papers . Can you please help ? Thanks

Comment: @Saun Dev  There are some talks that David Bressoud gave on the topic that you should be able to find if you search.

Comment: @SaunDev See [Volterra's paper](http://mathematica.sns.it/media/volumi/429/volterra_1.pdf), p. 43 of the pdf .

Comment: @SaunDev See [D.Bressoud's writing](http://www.macalester.edu/~bressoud/talks/AlleghenyCollege/Wrestling.pdf), p. 52 .